# python set literal doesn't work with list to create a set

Tags: python-3.x, list, set

I am trying to use a set literal `{}` to create a set from a list,

```
fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4']
{fields}

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

had to use `set(fields)` to create a set,

```
{'field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4'}
```

I am wondering what is the reason behind this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literals are not used to convert; the following won't convert a set to a list either:

```
aset = {'foo', 'bar'}
alist_from_aset = [aset]
```

That'd create a list with *one element*, the set. Your attempt tells Python to create a set with one element, but sets only take *hashable objects*, and a list is not such an object.

In recent Python 3 releases, you can use *iterable unpacking* to expand values into separate elements:

```
{*fields}
```

That unpacks all the values from a variable into separate values for a set literal:

```
>>> fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4']
>>> {*fields}
{'field2', 'field3', 'field1', 'field4'}
```

See [PEP 448 -- Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/); it's [new in Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations).

Answer (score 1):

With `{fields}` you're trying to make a new set with `fields` as an element, but list is not [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable), so Python complaints.

[`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) works another way, it expects iterables:

```
>>> set(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>> set('field1')
set(['e', 'd', 'f', 'i', 'l', '1'])
```

You can create a new set of `fields` values this way:

```
>>> fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field1']
>>> {*fields}
{'field1', 'field3', 'field4', 'field2'}
```

---

Note that you can't create an empty set with `{}` (that gives you a dict), you have to rely on `set()` in that cases.